# Resources on the Rotterdam demand system

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, demand-system-estimation

I've been doing some self study on the Almost Ideal Demand System, and have been hearing a lot about the Rotterdam demand system developed by  [Henri Theil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Theil).

I've been looking for resources on google scholar that provide an overview on it however I'm having difficulty finding anything comprehensive. Anyone on Econ.SE with slides/papers to reccomend or have a basic overview of the model they can share here?